# How to change (format) selected text, not whole selected cell using excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, select, text

For example cell "C3" contains text "France is huge". Some user with cursor highlights (selects) only the text "huge". Then using some macro the result should look like this "France is ***huge***". (The word "huge" is Italic bold and gray).
It is important to say that the length of the selected words are always different and I don't want to change the whole cell just selected text. I have been looking for this macro pretty much whole week but no result. Thank you for your help.

Comment: why don't you use Excel built-in formatting tools?

Comment: Users make a lot of text formatting in this sheet, not only "Italic, Bold and text color", sometimes also text size etc. And it takes a lot more time to click six or seven times to format selected text than click once on some button that have macro assigned. And it also reduce making mistakes in formatting.

Comment: there are shortcuts just a right-click away. and in any case, no, to my knowledge you can't invoke a macro while in edit mode. finally, if there's a lot of text formatting then you'd better think about using word...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

edited to make it more *easy*...

just for fun, I made up that functionality by means of a Userform

- open VBA IDE (keys: ALT-F11)
- add a UserForm (click Insert -> UserForm)

  this will add a new UserForm to your project

  change its default name (some "UserForm1" or the likes) to a meaningful one (e.g."UserFormFormat") by editing the "Name" textbox in the Property window (F4 to pop it out)
- show toolbox (click View -> ToolBox)
- grab a TextBox control and drop in your UserForm canvas
- grab a Button control and drop it in your Userform canvas
- select the Button in the Userform
- edit button "Name" (some "CommandButton1" by default) to some meaningful name (e.g.: "BtnBold")
- edit button "Caption" (some "CommandButton1" by default) to some meaningful name (e.g.: "Bold")
- double click the button on the Userform

  it'll open its CommandButton1_Click() event handler code pane
- insert code as to have the following

  ```
  Private Sub BtnBold_Click()
      With TextBox1
          ActiveCell.Characters(.SelStart, .SelLength + 1).Font.Bold = Not ActiveCell.Characters(.SelStart, .SelLength + 1).Font.Bold
      End With
      Me.Hide
  End Sub
  ```
- go to your excel UI
- click menu Development -> Macro
- in the "Macro" dialog box clear the "macro name" text box, insert a meaningful name (e.g.: "formatMacro") and press "Create" button

  this will take you to a new Module code pane with the following code

  ```
  Sub formatMacro()

  End Sub
  ```
- edit that code so as to have

  ```
  Sub formatMacro()
      With UserFormFormat
          .TextBox1.Text = Selection.Value2
          .Show
       End With
      Unload UserFormFormat
  End Sub
  ```
- follow [these instructions](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/878-excel-insert-macro-button.html) and add a button in the Quick Access Toolbar to run your macro
- go back to your Excel UI, select a cell with text and click the button you added in QAT
- watch what happens...

of course you can have one button do more formatting at a time

for instance you could add some other `BtnBold_Italic` button with "Bold & Italic" caption whose click event code would be:

```
    Private Sub BtnBold_Italic_Click()
        With TextBox1
            With ActiveCell.Characters(.SelStart, .SelLength + 1).Font
                .Bold = Not .Bold
                .Italic = Not .Italic
            End With
        End With
        Me.Hide
    End Sub
```

and so on (you may add text size, color... in one shot!)

Comment: Your "just for fun" functionality kinda works and I really appreciate your work for me but this doesn't solve my problem.You know, users who are  intended to use this macro are not simply able to do "complicated" things like ctrl + I, then choose the right button from user form and then close the user form. I really need to have macro that I could assign to one button and with this macro I want to be able to format selected text in a cell. I still want to believe there is some simple solution.

Comment: to add more fun, I edited the answer and added the following functionalities: 1) added _how to_ instructions to link the macro to a button in the QAT the user can click once it selects a cell she wants to format  (no need for Ctrl-Stuff) 2) the userform will hide and unload right after the user clicks the button (no need for the user to bother about clicking any button other than the one she _has_ to)

Comment: @Lajbror, let me know. I think this way is suited for the _unable_ user ...

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, sir. It seems to be working fine. I really appreciate your work for me.